# 2(3) questions about T4 templates, getting name of primary file being processed, and able to end processing?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, t4, dsl

I am trying to create my own DSL for a project, and I'd like to create one T4 file that contains the main engine for this, and then to create small T4 files that includes this engine and invokes it.

I was thinking of attempting this format for the T4 files that will invoke the engine:

```
<#@ include file="EngineLib\EngineLib.tt" #>
<# RunEngine(); #>
dsl goes here
```

The three questions I have are as follows:

### 1. Can I get the name of the primary script?

Basically, inside EngineLib.tt, can I retrieve the full path to and filename of the script that included it, in this case the script being shown above? Or, if not, the contents of it?

### 2. Can I end script processing?

For instance, inside the `RunEngine()` method, if the first question produces an answer, I would read through the original script, remove the first lines containing T4 directives, and then process the rest of the file according to my DSL rules.

Then, when `RunEngine` has produced the code result from that DSL, I would terminate processing of T4 code, so that the DSL itself isn't outputted as part of the generated file.

Did that make sense?

Assume RunEngine simply outputs a class, if I can't terminate processing, here's what the generated file would look like:

```
public class SomeClass
{
}
dsl goes here
```

Obviously I don't want the DSL code as part of my generated output.

### 3. Am I barking up the wrong tree?

I know that I can't include T4-like code in the DSL, since that would end up being compiled into code that would run as part of the T4 processing, but in this case it won't be a problem.

Anything else I haven't thought of that can go wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. To get name of the script, use `Host.TemplateFile`. To make the host available, add `hostspecific` property to the header:

   ```
   <#@ template language="C#v3.5" hostspecific="true" debug="true" #>
   ```
2. To stop processing the script, you can use `return` statement. Obviously, there is no way to do this inside another function, you must do it inside `<# #>` brackets.

   ```
   <# return GenerationEnvironment.ToString(); #>
   ```
3. What you try to achieve is usually done using two separate files: T4 script and data file it uses as source. To make the script update generated file when data file is changed, and to generate multiple files from one T4 script, you can use T4Toolbox.